# How to refactor file names in Android Studio in Dart or Flutter project?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, package, refactoring

When using android studio's refactoring tool `refactoring` -> `rename` to change file names or file paths it does not change the corresponding imports.

In Android projects this happens automatically, but when in a flutter project name changes of files breaks all classes importing the renamed file.

Is it possible to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the source of my problem.
`Search for references` and `Search in comments and strings` were unchecked.
Checking search for references solved the issue.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To rename files in Android Studio and changing the references of that fil in the code use `Refactor > Rename` on the file itself.

Comment: Strange. What version of Android Studio are you using ? Also what are the versions of the Flutter and Dart plugins ?

Comment: `Flutter (Channel stable, v1.5.4-hotfix.2, on Mac OS X 10.14.5 18F132)`, `Android SDK version 28.0.3`, `Android Studio (version 3.4)`  
Have you tried it on your machine?

Comment: Yes I did. Inside Android Studio you have two plugins installed (Flutter and Dart). What are their respective version number ?

Comment: `Flutter v37.0.1`, `Dart v183.6270`

Comment: This is not a new problem however.
I can't recall it ever working in a Dart environment.
Can some one else confirm it works on their machine.
I don't want to reset all my settings unless it's confirmed.

Comment: Well I'm working in a team of 4 and it works on every machine, even if they have different configuration (Mac OS and WIndows).

Answer (score 0):

Just check the Path of your main.dart file. Correct it like `..\HomePage\\main.dart` it will work.